# Battery refresh question

Tags: lumia-520

Should the battery be pulled to sort of "refresh" the phone just as it is recommended that you shut the phone down and restart it every couple days?

Comment: Where is it recommended to restart the phone every couple of days?

Comment: Check this link if you're looking for battery lifespan tips http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/keep-androids-battery-healthy-tips/

Answer (score 4):

*No*, the battery should not be pulled from the phone every two days.

**From a Windows Phone perspective**

There is no need to restart your phone every few days. In fact, the only time the phone needs to be restarted is when there is a system app (eg. the glace screen app) or system update (eg. the Denim update).

**From a battery perspective**

Removing it from the phone has no benefit whatsoever. Simply use your phone normally, and charge it when you can.